# Open a folder based on the date

Tags: command-line

Using command line is it possible to open a dynamic folder based on today's date?
Command line example:

```
cd /folderstatic/20200722/
```

where 20200722 is the dynamic command.

Comment: You are assuming a folder with the current date is already existing? Perhaps explain your use case a bit more specific.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you can create a `shell script` or add an `alias` on your `.bashrc`

But I'll go with the simplest.

**Approach using bash alias**

Simply add these lines on your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

```
# Create year, month and date format (Y-m-d)
# Ex. 20200722
folder_date=$(date +"%Y%m%d")

# Define a dynamic alias using the variable $folder_date
alias $folder_date="cd folder/static/$folder_date"
```

Then you can simply execute the command using the date today on your terminal.

Example:

```
$ 20200722
```

The command will navigate to the directory `folder/static/20200722`

Comment: Perhaps in many cases more theoretical than real, but if the user return next day to the same terminal window, the date will be wrong. Or if midnight passed...

Comment: Yeap, that's the downside of this approach. Maybe the user can reload their terminal (reopen) I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a combination of [`date`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html), [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) with `cd` using [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).

```
cd "/folderstatic/$(date +%F | sed s/-//g)"
```

`date +%F` would print date in YYYY-MM-DD format which will be passed to `sed` and there `-`(hyphens) would be replaced with empty string. The resultant `date +%F | sed s/-//g` would like

```
20200722
```

Comment: If I try to give this command line, and I have this error:
/folderstatic/$(date +%F | sed s/: No such file or directory

Comment: @mrc88 The starting quote of `-` must have been treated as ending quote of the location. I have removed that from my answer. Please try running command again.

Comment: I always have this result:
/$(date +%F | sed s/-//g): No such file or directory

Comment: @mrc88 Can you please share a screenshot. There must be something I'm missing. The command works fine on my installation under BASH as well as ZSH.

Comment: You can use `date +%Y%m%d` instead of `date +%F | sed s/-//g`.

Comment: Screenshot:
https://i.ibb.co/4pdY792/Schermata-2020-07-22-alle-12-17-33.png

Comment: @mrc88 What is the output of `type -a cd`? And why are you using root account?

Comment: @mrc88, please provide the output of the `pwd` command within the circumstances of the screenshot.

Comment: The output is:
-a: not found
cd is a shell builtin
Is the root account not good?

The output of pwd is the present folder "/var/Rimini"

Comment: @mrc88, using root account directly is not good idea at all and it is not necessary for the most tasks. I suppose you've created few directories on wrong places. I think you need to read an article as [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/#:~:text=An%20absolute%20path%20is%20defined%20as%20specifying%20the%20location%20of,actual%20file%20system%20from%20%2F%20directory.&text=Relative%20path%20is%20defined%20as,present%20working%20directly(pwd).) in rder to understand the difference between the terms absolute and relative path.

Comment: @mrc88 Are you even using Ubuntu? What is the output of `SHELL --version`?

Comment: My ubuntu version https://i.ibb.co/Z8vzKfk/Schermata-2020-07-22-alle-12-55-02.png

Comment: @mrc88 I meant `$SHELL --version`. (I don't know I missed `$`)

Comment: $SHELL --version = sh: 1: --version: not found

Comment: @pa4080 I believe that if "root" can create a folder, it can also open and read it. No?

Comment: @mrc88 Seems like an sh specific issue. Can you switch to other shell such as BASH or ZSH?

Comment: You are right. It's a permission issue. I downloaded via SSH and it works! Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

You quickest method I know of is the fzf search tool. Once installed you simply type:
fzf ** <>TAB> and then enter the date (or part of) the file or folder name.